# 'CSRF token not found' on non-authentication routes

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-blade

I'm creating a Laravel site for a small business. There's a public front-end and a 'admin panel' for managing data, customer information and a blog.

I have created a 'Public Controller' for managing requests made on the public routes (home page, privacy policy, gallery, etc.) which does not implement the Auth middleware, and I have separate controllers for things like the blog and dashboard which do implement the Auth middleware and do usual CRUD.

There are two layouts - one 'admin' and one 'user', the difference being the way the navbar is displayed and the wrapping elements around the content @yield. Both layouts @include a 'head' layout which has the  tags, including the CSRF token.

My problem is that whenever I go to pages that aren't '/login', '/admin' or '/dashboard' (Dashboard is accessible once Authenticated), I get an error in console about the CSRF token.

The CSRF token is visible in the HTML on all of the pages, Auth and non-Auth, but it's only on '/login' (And the other default Auth pages provided by make:auth) and '/dashboard' that the system doesn't throw a fit about it.

I've tried:

- Re-writing the  tag to make sure
  there's no typos
- Someone's suggestion to change app.js line of

`let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');`

to

`let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

- I've tried php artisan config:clear and composer dump-autoload
- I've tried adding the Auth middleware to PublicController.php

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    if ( Auth::user() ) {
        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'PublicController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
```

**user.blade.php** *(The 'public' layout for non auth routes)* AND **admin.blade.php** *(The 'private' layout for auth routes[internal])*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
@include('layouts.head')
<body>
    <div id="app">
...
```

**head.blade.php:**

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>@yield('title')</title>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">/script>

<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@yield('css')
```

**publicController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the home page
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**DashController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something obvious but I'm really not sure where to go now since I've tried every answer on google now despite there being a clear correlation between the pages you don't need to be auth'ed playing up with CSRF and those that check if you're an Auth user being fine, even though both include the same 'head' layout which has CSRF in it.

**EDIT**

The Kernel.php by request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];

/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error you get in the console please?

Comment: app.js:1 CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Are you making any ajax requests?

Comment: I am not, no. The app is pretty bare-bones at this point.

Comment: add `@csrf` after `form` in your view file.

Comment: I've wrapped my  home.blade `@section('content')` layout in a `<form>` and added `@csrf` but the issue persists.

Comment: @MateuszSromala are you getting this issue with GET or POST request? I mean just clicking on any link or you are trying to submit a form?

Comment: I'd assume GET, I'm not submitting any forms - just navigating the home page `127.0.0.1:8000`, or the other pages like `127.0.0.1/blog`

Comment: For now, can you just disabled this from `kernal.php` `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`

Comment: And try to click on link. Let me know once it work... also please share your kernal.php file.

Comment: This stops the error but I assume I'll be at the same position as now once I add a contact form to the home page and need CSRF again, so it's not really a solution. I'll post the Kernel in an edit.

Comment: This was just for debug... not the solution....your kernal.php looks good. Now enabled that and comment the Auth::routes() or place that at last.

Comment: I assume you mean Auth::routes() in web.php. Commenting out that line breaks the dashboard (route logout not defined) and the issue with CSRF still continues in the home page. Placing it last has no effect on anything.

Comment: What is the session driver in `.env`?

Comment: `SESSION_DRIVER=file` 
`SESSION_LIFETIME=120`

Comment: @MateuszSromala make sure the `storage` directory have writtable permission recursively till `storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: I've temporarily given the Users and Everyone object Full Permissions to `storage` and everything within but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you get files inside this `storage/framework/sessions`

Comment: Inside `storage/framework/sessions` is a 1kb file with a random character string for a name (9ZuZz4TeOaAQGeKN87jV....) and no extension, and a .gitignore file

Comment: this is not needed in header `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` why you have added this?

Comment: I thought that you need to include the csrf token in the head per the Docs and some old code I was using. I've tried removing the tag just, but the issue is still there.